# How to continue animation progress in Plymouth script?

Tags: theme, plymouth, animation

Is it possible to continue the animation progress in a Plymouth theme until the animation has ended and is ready to quit. I am creating a custom one for my OS and i want to show up the display manager only when the Plymouth theme script has completed its animation and is ready to quit.

Comment: any answer or suggestion please?